# How to use sumifs to total tips by time range?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a tip report that gives me tips by specific time. I need to sum the tips for each hour of the day starting at 5AM. When using sumifs, I'm able to sum the total without the second criteria range. Could someone help? Thanks!
Here is the code I am using.
=SUMIFS($D$4:$D$283,$C$4:$C$283,">="&G4,$C$4:$C$283,"<="&H4)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YJ9n.png

Comment: Is what is in cell G4 the same as in column C? Tet just that without the rest of the sumifs()

Comment: If you are getting 0 as result, your data has been probably registered with the rest of the date included. You can check that by changing the hour format from `hh:mm:ss` to `gg/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss`. Do you confirm it? Also: i guess you'll check just one day at time, right?

Comment: There was a date included so that was the problem. I would like to set it up to where I can copy and past the tip table and have the data populate on the right but this is what I came up with for now. I removed the date C4 and the formula's working. Thank you!

Comment: Check the solution i've provided. You can basically use an extra column to extract the hour and then use it in a simple `SUMIF` to get the result. This way you'll can just copy-paste the tip table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Time | Tip | Hour | =IF(COUNTA(A:A)>COUNTA(C:C),"Increase Hour column length","Hour column lenght checked") | Hour | Tips' total by hour |
| 44796,2471064815 | 2,4 | =HOUR(A2) |  | 5 | =SUMIF(C:C,E2,B:B) |
| 44796,2731134259 | 5,04 | =HOUR(A3) |  | 6 | =SUMIF(C:C,E3,B:B) |
| 44796,2751967593 |  | =HOUR(A4) |  | 7 | =SUMIF(C:C,E4,B:B) |
| 44796,2773958333 | 3,32 | =HOUR(A5) |  | 8 | =SUMIF(C:C,E5,B:B) |
| 44796,2843055556 | 4,03 | =HOUR(A6) |  | 9 | =SUMIF(C:C,E6,B:B) |
| 44796,284375 | 5,81 | =HOUR(A7) |  | 10 | =SUMIF(C:C,E7,B:B) |
| 44796,2847800926 | 6,47 | =HOUR(A8) |  | 11 | =SUMIF(C:C,E8,B:B) |
| 44796,2855787037 | 4,53 | =HOUR(A9) |  | 12 | =SUMIF(C:C,E9,B:B) |
| 44796,2857986111 | 3,65 | =HOUR(A10) |  | 13 | =SUMIF(C:C,E10,B:B) |
| 44796,2880208333 | 3,32 | =HOUR(A11) |  | 14 | =SUMIF(C:C,E11,B:B) |
| 44796,2891203704 | 3,3 | =HOUR(A12) |  | 15 | =SUMIF(C:C,E12,B:B) |
| 44796,2896990741 | 2,7 | =HOUR(A13) |  | 16 | =SUMIF(C:C,E13,B:B) |
| 44796,2913888889 |  | =HOUR(A14) |  | 17 | =SUMIF(C:C,E14,B:B) |
| 44796,2928935185 |  | =HOUR(A15) |  | 18 | =SUMIF(C:C,E15,B:B) |
| 44796,2988425926 | 2,18 | =HOUR(A16) |  | 19 | =SUMIF(C:C,E16,B:B) |
| 44796,3238194444 | 2,88 | =HOUR(A17) |  | 20 | =SUMIF(C:C,E17,B:B) |
|  |  |  |  | 21 | =SUMIF(C:C,E18,B:B) |
|  |  |  |  | 22 | =SUMIF(C:C,E19,B:B) |
|  |  |  |  | 23 | =SUMIF(C:C,E20,B:B) |
|  |  |  |  | 24 | =SUMIF(C:C,E21,B:B) |